# I am having difficulty finding the unique multi index tuple of my dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I am having difficulty finding the unique multi index tuple of my dataframe.

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 5)), columns=list('ABCDF'))
df = df.set_index(['A','B','C'])
print(df)
```

I need to find the nth row index i.e. the values in A,B,C.

This tuple which I pick up will then be used to query a separate df which appears to be working fine.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df.index[n]
```

Example for the fifth (n=4) row:

```
(81, 37, 25)
```

Comment: yep - that worked. And that was super simple. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

@MatthewHooper, for getting the value of nth index in pandas use the **index method** for getting the values of nth columns use **iloc method** For example

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100,5)), columns=list('ABCDF'))

# Set index using column
df = df.set_index(['A','B','C'])
```

#### Print the 5 first values

```py
print(df.head(5))
```

**Output**

```sh
           D   F
A  B  C         
19 32 44  43  94
32 1  76  79   4
2  96 76  80  77
68 67 42  87  50
20 68 14   4   9
```

#### Find the 5th row index

```py
print(df.index[4])
```

**Output**

```sh
(20, 68, 14)
```

#### Find the 5th columns values

```py
print(tuple(df.iloc[4]))
```

**Output**

```sh
(4, 9)
```